# CodeIgniter redirect URL after unpermitted uri remove char

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, hook

I'm working in a CodeIgnitier project. We have many data with a wrong configuration so many URL contains unicode chars and others undesirables chars.
Clean all data will take several months and I want to avoid 400 errors due to **permitted_uri_chars**. The ressources are accessibles if I remove undesirables chars. I would like automatically remove these chars.
I try to put the following code in application/config/routes.php :

```
if ($this->uri->total_segments()) {
  foreach (range(1, $this->uri->total_segments()) as $i) {
      if ($this->uri->segment($i)) {
          $this->uri->segments[$i] = preg_replace("#[^".$this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars')."]#i", "", $this->uri->segments[$i]);
      }
  }
}
```

But I get the 400 error. CodeIgniter controls URLs before passing in routes.php. Where can I put my code to avoid 400 error ?
Can I do that in pre_system hook ?

Comment: You can extend `URI` and `Router` core classes. More infos https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Thank you, it's the solution I will choose. I just try others things before.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand this code and put on top into your header file. You can manage your url as you want.

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);

if($id)
{
    $url = str_replace('/'.$id,"",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
} else {
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

$pattern = '/([A-Z]+)/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $url))
{
    $new_url = strtolower($url);
    Header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
    if($id){
        Header( 'Location: ' . $new_url.'/'.$id );
    } else {
        Header( 'Location: ' . $new_url );
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what is your **header file** ? I will be rejected before access controler or route file.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, my header file mean ..you can put this code on the top of your file.
Are you reaching till top of the file?

Comment: Thanks for answer but... Google will not like me if I make many 301 redirect of sitemaps URLs. I found another solution that I give as answer. I give you +1 because your solution is good but not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I use a solution to avoid 301 redirections. I don't want Google hate me because I send sitemaps with several 301 redirections. I allow certains chars but remove these in routes file.

In my config.php file :

```
$config['permitted_removed_uri_chars'] = '\',ß';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9%.:_\-+&'.$config['permitted_removed_uri_chars'];
```

In my routes.php files :

```
if ($this->uri->total_segments()) {
    foreach (range(1, $this->uri->total_segments()) as $i) {
        if ($this->uri->segment($i)) {
            $this->uri->segments[$i] = preg_replace("#[".$this->config->item('permitted_removed_uri_chars')."]#i", "", $this->uri->segments[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```